# sql server service disabled, and/or greyed-out

Tags: sql-server

I just installed SQL Server on my laptop.  It won't start and it seems like all the services are disabled, and/or greyed-out.  I have never seen this before.  It seems very weird to me.  Does anyone here have any idea what is going on?

Everything in the Configuration Manager is stopped and I can't start it.  I think this is because of the Services not running.  I'm not sure though....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to run `Configuration Manager` or `services.msc` as `Admin` user else it will be greyd out as you seeing. See this [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx) and as it says:

> Permissions
>
> By default, only members of the local **administrators group** can
>   start, stop, pause, resume or restart a service. To grant
>   non-administrators the ability to manage services, see [How to grant
>   users rights to manage services in Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325349). (The process
>   is similar on other versions of Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.  I had to get the IT team to login with Admin rights and start the SQL Server services.  All set now.